# Input data is not being loaded into registers - issues only in post-synthesis timing simulation [VHDL][Vivado] (SOLVED)

Tags: vhdl, vivado

**What this is**

I'm trying to create a simple FIR filter. What I'm going to present you may not exactly be a FIR filter as I'm gradually increasing complexity of my project for educational purpouses till it reaches desired functionality.

**What it should be doing**

Basically what it should be doing so far:

- load data to registers after applying load = 1,
- unload processed data (which is product of multiplication of samples with corresponding coefficients) after applying start = 1.

**Where it fails**

However from what I've noticed it fails to load data into registers. Seems to be working like a latch, as after *load* drops to 0, the last vector value at input port is being latched in the registers. But I may be wrong, it just appears to be working like this in simulation.
**Pre- and post-synthesis functional simulation is working! Only the post-synthesis timing is failing to work as desired!**

**What I've tried**

- Adding DONT_TOUCH parameter to entity declaration in its .vhd file,
- Adding kind of buffer (unsigned variable) after data_in port from which the data is being transfered to  registers - but it did not even appear in schematic after synthesis, maybe the DONT_TOUCH did not work?

**Simulations pictures**

Pre-synth functional - https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp9H2.jpg

Post-synth timing - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOj4A.jpg

**Program**

I'm using Vivado 2020.2 webpack

**Testbench**

Testbench code here: https://pastebin.pl/view/d2f9a4ad

**Main code**

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

entity fir is
 Port ( 
 clk: in std_logic;
 data_in: in unsigned(7 downto 0);
 data_out: out unsigned(7 downto 0);
 en: in std_logic;
 load: in std_logic;
 start: in std_logic;
 reset: in std_logic
 );
end fir;

architecture Behavioral of fir is

-- type coeff_array is array (0 to 7) of integer range 0 to 255;
constant reg_size: integer := 8;
constant filter_order: integer := 7;

type samples_reg is array (0 to reg_size-1) of unsigned(7 downto 0);
type coeffs_reg is array (0 to filter_order) of unsigned(7 downto 0);


begin

process(clk, reset)
     
    -- variable coeffs: coeff_array := (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    --variable b0: unsigned(7 downto 0) := 8D"0";
    variable b0: unsigned(7 downto 0) := to_unsigned(1,8);
    variable b1: unsigned(7 downto 0) := to_unsigned(2,8);
    variable b2: unsigned(7 downto 0) := to_unsigned(3,8);
    variable b3: unsigned(7 downto 0) := to_unsigned(4,8);
    variable b4: unsigned(7 downto 0) := to_unsigned(5,8);
    variable b5: unsigned(7 downto 0) := to_unsigned(6,8);
    variable b6: unsigned(7 downto 0) := to_unsigned(7,8);
    variable b7: unsigned(7 downto 0) := to_unsigned(8,8);
    
    variable i: integer range 0 to reg_size := 0;
    
    variable samples: samples_reg := (others => (others => '0'));
    variable coeffs: coeffs_reg := (b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7);
    
    variable data_processed: unsigned(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    
       
    
    
    -- variable reg_element:
    
    -- signal s1 : signed(47 downto 0) := 48D"46137344123";
    
    begin    
    
    if reset = '1' then
        -- data_out <= (others => '0');
        samples := (others => (others => '0'));
        data_processed := (others => '0');
        i := 0;            

    -- synch part
    elsif rising_edge(clk) and en = '1' then
    
    samples := samples;
        
        -- loading data
        if load = '1' then
            samples(i) := data_in;
            
            i := i+1;
        else null;
        end if;                      
        
        -- deloading data
        if start = '1' then
            
        data_processed := samples(i)*coeffs(i);
        i := i+1;
        else null; 
        end if;
            
        -- reset counter after overflow
        if(i = reg_size) then
            i := 0;
        else null;
        end if;
        
        -- reset counter if no data is being transferred
        if load = '0' and start = '0' then
            i := 0;
            data_processed := (others => '0');
        else null;
        end if;    
                    
    end if;
    
    data_out <= data_processed(7 downto 0);
    
 end process;


end Behavioral;
```

**Other info**

- I just noticed that I'm holding load = 1 for one excessive cycle, which is why the highest number appears first.
- The coefficients are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.
- In post-synth simulations after peeking into UUT, I've noticed that the samples registers are not loading the data (except for the last one, as I've mentioned earlier), the *i* is incrementing and the rest appears to be working properly.
- I'll be happy to hear about some improvements for my code in addition to the problem solution!

Comment: Instead of `elsif rising_edge(clk) and en = '1' then` write

```
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
  if en = '1' then
   ....
  end if;
end if;
```

Comment: And you cannot iterate over `i` inside a process in this way. Use a `for` statement.

Comment: @OronPort I don't quite understand how to use `for` statement when I want to add (or output) new data each clock cycle. Won't the for loop execute in one clock cycle? Could you present an example or implement this in my code?

Comment: I suggest you start from drawing the circuit. From that it will be easier for you to understand how a for statement is useful here. The `for` is generating wires. The cycle is "advanced" only at the end of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in timing simulation I had to give the device at least 100 ns of warm-up time.

Seems like the timing simulations takes some factors related to device start-up into consideration -- anyway, I'm not sure about the explanation but I am sure of the above solution.

I have rephrased the title so others can find this post by searching for core problem in this case.

Good luck :)